# Sharepoint site Windows authentication and FBA

Tags: 2007, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have an Extranet that use SharePoint 2007. The users of this Site use Windows Authentication(AD) but there is also some External Partners that use this Site that don't have AD is it possible to make it so, AD and FBA are used. So the people that are already users use AD and the External Partners are set up with and use FBA. Would it be a case of extending the Web Application and then setting up FBA and both of them will now work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes both FBA and NTLM can co-exists. Enabling FBA will not affect your existing site users.

This involves 3 steps

1. Extend SharePoint Web Application
2. Update Web Configuration entries
3. Make changes in Central Admin to enable FBA

You can go through technet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262201(v=office.12).aspx article. Which explains each step in detail.

Comment: grrrr why can't I mark this as right now haha, thank you :). I'll mark it in 7 min

Comment: It will affect existing users. If both authentication modes are enabled, users will be prompted to select "windows authentication" or "forms authentication" via a dropdown prior to logging in. This is not a huge deal, except 1) most users won't know what the choices mean, and will need to be told what to select, and 2) the page is very, very basic, and will not appeal to anyone with any sort of standards re UI (developers will think it looks fine. ;)  )